# ComparatorChain vs Convert property to String and compare

Tags: java, performance, comparator

I have a List of element. Each element that has four props.

> 1. A Date Obj.
> 2. An Enum Obj (values are {E-4,D-3,C-2,B-1,A-0})
> 3. Another Date Obj
> 4. Another Date Obj.

Currently I'm sorting the list using a `comparator[MyObjComparator]` where I'm converting each props into `String` and appending the Strings in a `StringBuilder` and then comparing the resultant Strings. 
I'm using dateFormat as `yyyyMMddHHmmss`.

Another approach can be having a `compatorChain`. I can create some inner comparator class in `MyObjComparator` [We can't avoid the use of this. All impl must go inside the compareTo] and add them to build a comparator chain and use it.

Now my Question is which one will be good in terms of performance or longevity ?

Edit 1:
All four properties should be included in comparison.
Adding a code snap
1. Checking each property indivitualy

```
 package com.poc.MultiPropComparator.service;

 import java.util.Comparator;
 import java.util.Date;
 import com.poc.MultiPropComparator.domain.MyDomainObject;
 import com.poc.MultiPropComparator.domain.PropertyType;

 public class MyDomainObjectComparator implements Comparator<MyDomainObject>{

    @Override
    public int compare(MyDomainObject o1, MyDomainObject o2) {

        Date recordDate1 = o1.getRecordDate();
        Date recordDate2 = o2.getRecordDate();

        if(recordDate1.compareTo(recordDate2)==0){
            return compareType(o1,o2);
        }
        return recordDate1.compareTo(recordDate2);
    }

    private int compareType(MyDomainObject o1, MyDomainObject o2) {

        PropertyType type1 = o1.getType();
        PropertyType type2 = o2.getType();

        if(type1.compareTo(type2)==0){
            return compareStartDate(o1,o2);
        }

        return type1.compareTo(type2);
    }

    private int compareStartDate(MyDomainObject o1, MyDomainObject o2) {

        Date startDate1 = o1.getStartDate();
        Date startdDate2 = o2.getStartDate();

        if(startDate1.compareTo(startdDate2)==0){
            return compareEndDate(o1,o2);
        }
        return startDate1.compareTo(startdDate2);
    }

    private int compareEndDate(MyDomainObject o1, MyDomainObject o2) {
        Date endDate1 = o1.getEndDate();
        Date endDate2 = o2.getEndDate();

        return endDate1.compareTo(endDate2);
    }


}
```

Comment: Why not compare the dates directly? Dates implement Comparable<Date>...

Comment: And why not benchmark both approaches? Personally I'd avoid string conversions wherever possible, but if you're interested in one particular aspect you can just test that.

Comment: You have to give priority to your checks. For example, firstly, compare the first date objects. If equal, compare the enum objects. Etc. Could you provide the way your building the StringBuilder? You must have done it automatically.

Comment: @sp00m The Comparator could append in descending priority order and use a fixed width format for each field.

Answer (score 1):

A `ComparatorChain` (you are referring to the Apache Commons class right?) with individual comparators based in the primitive (or almost-primitive) types instead of `String` conversions should have better if not much better performance.  In particular, `ComparatorChain` stops evaluating as soon as it can make a decision (pretty much like the shortcut and (`&&`) and shortcut or (`||`) operators).  In a `String`-based comparison you need to generate both comparand `String`s in full before even starting the comparison (unless you want to mix both schemes, which doesn't make any sense).

In terms of longevity, the string concatenation is due to fail on year 10,000.  That's a certainty.  Jokes apart, a `ComparatorChain` strategy is much easier to maintain, and supports posible modification to the `enum`, as well as addition of fields to the comparison, in a much better way.